# How can I enable debug log for ActionMailer in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, redmine, bitnami

I run into problems with my SMTP email settings for BitNami Redmine 2.1.0. In order to check the used values, I need full debug log of the Action_Mailer which is responsible for all the SMTP communication. I've already include

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

in production.rb but this doesn't show the SMTP communication instead of it shows all the other ruby stuff. What is needed to see the SMTP communication between Redmine and the configured SMTP server?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to set "config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true" and see if you get more information?